# Graph API Facebook

Tags: facebook

Is Facebook graph API enough secure to store and retrieve data? Apparently, it's quite easy to access information of some unknown person with appropriate query. I would like to know is there any security threat of making personal information public? If anyone has any idea please share.

Answer (score 2):

All depends on the permission.Here is the link for facebook app permission.

[Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

It works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

user has to give you permissions first before you're allowed to access his private informations.

To store data -> what do you mean? It's not storage engine
To retreive data -> PHP sdk uses https protocol so yes, it's secured

Comment: I meant the information stored in server. When any application is used by any user, the object created stores the ID of the user provided by fb. That is basically used for mapping all information. So, does it make information open to the programmer?

Answer (score 0):

The only information you can get from the graph is public info, or content which you have a valid access token for.

If you have stored a user's Facebook ID, you can still only access their information when you have a valid access token.  That could either be obtained by having the user authenticate with Facebook, or by requesting the offline_access permission from the user.  With offline_access, the life of the access token is dramatically extended, meaning that you can make API calls on the users behalf while they are offline, but you can still only perform actions that the user has granted permission for.

Whether you should make your personal information public on social networks and what security ramifications sharing your personal information has is a whole other discussion, and not really suited to this site.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the permission from the user to access his profile, you can view all the information which USER WANTS you to see.